# How to parse response from Twitter Streaming API?

Tags: json, twitter

I'm trying to create a datavisualisation website like this one => http://www.nohomophobes.com/#!/today/

For that, I'm using the Twitter streaming Api but I'm having problems to parse the response and the Twitter documentation is not that clear about the way to do it. The response is formatted like this: http://pastebin.com/ADUCWta7

I tried to parse that response with jQuery function JSON.parse, but it doesn't works...

Hope someone can help me... Thanks in advance!

Bastien

Comment: Hi, dont know if will help but i wrote this little c# library to work with json requests (https://github.com/ademargomes/JsonRequest) and in the test project there is a twitter example. Hope it helps.

Also here is the example file: https://github.com/ademargomes/JsonRequest/blob/master/JsonRequest.Tests/JsonRequestTwitterTests.cs